# Designing a multithreaded application that scales well

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization, vcl

The code below is a demonstration of what I'm trying to do and it has the same problem as my original code (which is not included here). I have spectrogram code and I'm trying to improve its performance by using multiple threads (my computer has 4 cores). The spectrogram code basically computes an FFT over many overlapping frames (these frames correspond to sound samples at a particular time).

As an example let's say that we have 1000 frames which overlap by 50%. 
If we're using 4 threads, then each thread should handle 250 frames. Overlapping frames just means that if our frames are 1024 samples in length, the first
frame has the range 0-1023, the second frame 512-1535, the third 1024-2047 etc (an overlap of 512 samples ).

The code creating and using the threads

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    numThreads = 4;
    fftLen = 1024;
    numWindows = 10000;
    int startTime = GetTickCount();

    numOverlappingWindows = numWindows*2;
    overlap = fftLen/2;
    const unsigned numElem = fftLen*numWindows+overlap;

    rx = new float[numElem];
    for(int i=0; i<numElem; i++) {
        rx[i] = rand();
    }
    useThreads = true;
    vWThread.reserve(numOverlappingWindows);

    if(useThreads){
    for(int i=0;i<numThreads;i++){
            TWorkerThread *pWorkerThread = new TWorkerThread(true); 
            pWorkerThread->SetWorkerMethodCallback(&CalculateWindowFFTs);//this is called in TWorkerThread::Execute
            vWThread.push_back(pWorkerThread);
        }
        pLock = new TCriticalSection();

        for(int i=0;i<numThreads;i++){ //start the threads
            vWThread.at(i)->Resume();
        }

        while(TWorkerThread::GetNumThreads()>0);
        }else CalculateWindowFFTs();

        int endTime = GetTickCount();

        Label1->Caption = IntToStr(endTime-startTime);
}
void TForm1::CalculateWindowFFTs(){

        unsigned startWnd = 0, endWnd = numOverlappingWindows, threadId;

        if(useThreads){
            threadId = TWorkerThread::GetCurrentThreadId();
            unsigned wndPerThread = numOverlappingWindows/numThreads;
            startWnd = (threadId-1)*wndPerThread;
            endWnd   =  threadId*wndPerThread;

        if(numThreads==threadId){
            endWnd = numOverlappingWindows;
            }
        }

    float *pReal, *pImg;

    for(unsigned i=startWnd; i<endWnd; i++){

            pReal = new float[fftLen];
            pImg  = new float[fftLen];

            memcpy(pReal, &rx[i*overlap], fftLen*sizeof(float));
            memset(pImg, '0', fftLen);
            FFT(pReal, pImg, fftLen);  //perform an in place FFT

            pLock->Acquire();
            vWndFFT.push_back(pReal);
            vWndFFT.push_back(pImg);
            pLock->Release();
    }
}

void TForm1::FFT(float *rx, float *ix, int fftSize)
{
    int i, j, k, m;
    float rxt, ixt;

    m = log(fftSize)/log(2);
    int fftSizeHalf = fftSize/2;
    j = k = fftSizeHalf;

        for (i = 1; i < (fftSize-1); i++){
            if (i < j) {

            rxt = rx[j];
            ixt = ix[j];
            rx[j] = rx[i];
            ix[j] = ix[i];
            rx[i] = rxt;
            ix[i] = ixt;
            }
            k = fftSizeHalf;

            while (k <= j){
                j = j - k;
                k = k/2;
                }
            j = j + k;

        }    //end for
    int le, le2, l, ip;
    float sr, si, ur, ui;
    for (k = 1; k <= m; k++) {
        le = pow(2, k);
        le2 = le/2;
        ur = 1;
        ui = 0;
        sr = cos(PI/le2);
        si = -sin(PI/le2);
        for (j = 1; j <= le2; j++) {
            l = j - 1;
            for (i = l; i < fftSize; i += le) {
                ip = i + le2;
                rxt = rx[ip] * ur - ix[ip] * ui;
                ixt = rx[ip] * ui + ix[ip] * ur;
                rx[ip] = rx[i] - rxt;
                ix[ip] = ix[i] - ixt;
                rx[i] = rx[i] + rxt;
                ix[i] = ix[i] + ixt;
            }    //end for
            rxt = ur;
            ur = rxt * sr - ui * si;
            ui = rxt * si + ui * sr;
        }
    }
}
```

While it's easy to divide this process over multiple threads, the performance is only marginally improved compared to the single-threaded version (<10%). 
Interestingly if I increase the number of threads to, say, 100, I do get an increase in speed of about 25%, which is surprising because 
I'd expect that thread context-switching overhead be a factor in this case.

At first I thought that the main reason for the poor performance is a lock on writing to a vector object so I experimented with an array of vectors (a 
vector per thread), thus eliminiting the need for the locks but the performance remained pretty much the same.

```
pVfft = new vector<float*>[numThreads];//create an array of vectors

  //and then in CalculateWindowFFTs, do something like

    vector<float*> &vThr = pVfft[threadId-1];
    for(unsigned i=startWnd; i<endWnd; i++){

            pReal = new float[fftLen];
            pImg  = new float[fftLen];

            memcpy(pReal, &rx[i*overlap], fftLen*sizeof(float));
            memset(pImg, '0', fftLen);
            FFT(pReal, pImg, fftLen);  //perform an in place FFT

            vThr.push_back(pReal);      
    }
```

I think I'm running into caching problems here though I'm not certain how to go about changing my design in order to have a solution that scales well.

I can also provide the code for TWorkerThread if you think that's important.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

As suggested by `1201ProgramAlarm` I removed that while loop and got about 15-20% speed improvement on my system. Now my main thread is not actively waiting for the threads to finish but rather I have `TWorkerThread` execute code on the main thread via `TThread::Synchronize` after all the worker threads have finished (i.e.when `numThreads` has reached 0).

While this is looking better now, it's still far from being optimal.

Comment: Well, instead of guessing I'd suggest using a good profiler for C++. There is plenty

Comment: Are you profiling a release or a debug build?

Comment: It's a debug build.

Comment: Can someone please help me with this? I understand this is not an easy question because one can't just google the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The locks to write to `vWndFFT` will hurt, as will the repeated (leaking) calls to `new` assigned to `pReal` and `pImg` (these should be outside the for loop).

But the real performance killer is probably your loop waiting for the threads to finish:  `while(TWorkerThread::GetNumThreads()>0);`.  This will consume one available thread in a very unfriendly way.

One quick fix (not recommended) would be to add a `sleep(1)` (or 2, 5, or 10) so the loop is not continuous.

A better solution would be to have the main thread be one of your calculation threads, and have a way for that thread (once it is done with all processing) to simply wait for the other thread to finish without consuming a core, using something like `WaitForMultipleObjects` that is available on Windows.

One simple way to try out your threaded code is simply to run threaded, but only use one thread.  Performance should be about the same as the non-threaded version, and the results should match.

Comment: I did already try using only 1 thread for the threaded version and it performed about the same as the non-threaded one so no surprises there. I also can get rid of the lock as I mentioned in my post but that didn't help either.

Comment: thank you for your answer. There are no leaking calls to `new` in the for loop and these calls must be inside the loop as they represent subsequent overlapping FFT frames. I store the pointers in  `vWndFFT` so they can be freed later when no longer needed. As for `while (TWorkerThread::GetNumThreads()>0);`, this call is executed in the context of the main thread but I do understand that it unnecessarily consumes a lot of processing time. Your suggestion to include the main thread as one of the calculation threads seems good, although I really have to try that to be sure.

Comment: I think I can do away with that while loop altogether. Since I'm decrementing `numThreads`, I can call `TThread::Synchronize(&NotifyFinished)` when `numThreads` reaches 0. The callback `NotifyFinished` is executed on the main thread. Not sure if this will improve performance though.